# How to create list with strings being part of another list

Tags: string, list, dart, flutter

I have a list of object which consists of 2 strings - `class X {StringA, StringB;}`. I need a list of concatenated values of string A and String B (`StringA + StringB`) and also apply a filter to it. Filter is like - `StringA.contains(pattern) || StringB.contains(pattern)`. How do I acheive this? I tried using toList but since my initial list is not of strings, I am unable to understand.

Comment: `"but since my initial list is not of strings, I am unable to understand."` - use `Iterable#map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
initialList
  .where((e) => e.StringA.contains(pattern) || e.StringB.contains(pattern))
  .map((e) => '${e.StringA}${e.StringB}')
  .toList()
```

Comment: I was missing the mapping. You are awesome. Thanks :)